# Is it possible to create an elseif statement with GTL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, gtl

I have created the following:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

var json = Attribute.GetValue('adressen');
var jsonObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(json);

if (jsonObj.length > 0) {

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++ ) {

      var item = jsonObj[i];

      Platform.Variable.SetValue("@adressoort",item['adressoort']);
      Platform.Variable.SetValue("@persoonsnaam",item['persoonsnaam']);
      Platform.Variable.SetValue("@bedrijfsnaam",item['bedrijfsnaam']);


      </script>
```

But when I try to set something it does not work:

```
%%[
IF @adressoort == '1' then
set @subjectKlant = [bedrijfsnaam]
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@subjectKlant)=%%
```

Comment: I'd recommend dumping GTL for SSJS.  SF has admitted that GTL was never fully implemented in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that the order should always be if...else if... else, with else always being the last. This is because else will capture the remainder and treat that condition as true - essentially ending the condition. As it runs in a cascading fashion, your elseif would either be ignored or cause an error.

Second, officially you could do something like:

```
    {{#if bedrijfsnaam!="a"}} SHOW FIELD {{/if}}
    {{#if bedrijfsnaam!="b"}} SHOW FIELD {{else}} SHOW DEFAULT {{/if}}
```

Which would accomplish the same thing, but it would be opening multiple if statements. It is far from best practice and I would avoid this way if possible. Why did I present it and show it first? Well, because it is the only way this is documented inside the **[official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/gtlDynamicContent.html)**. (under Create an Email Message)

Now, supposedly GTL can handle most of Handlebars syntax...I have seen this as well as the official GTL documentation be terribly wrong, so I put this as second to try, but know it might not work or potentially throw some unexpected behaviors.

The Handlebars syntax for an else if is as follows:

```
{{if a=="b"}} DO SOMETHING
{{else if a=="c"}} DO SOMETHING ELSE
{{else}} DEFAULT OUTPUT
{{/if}}
```

Hopefully that syntax works (I did not test it) and you can do it the more performant and efficient way, but I have such a strong distaste for GTL, I just could not bring myself to validate it on my own. I wish you good luck and hopefully it works well for you!